# What does module linking in python mean

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I'm not sure what exactly module linking means in python. For example, in spacy issues, I see https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1523.

`python -m spacy link jieba zh`

How does this work?

Most importantly, how I do ensure this happens in `requirements.txt` or somewhere programmatically?

Comment: Module linking is not a thing. You're extrapolating too much from the name of one argument in one command line. That's not even an argument to Python itself.

Answer (score 6):

"Module linking" is not the name of any concept in Python's module system. I don't know where you got the idea that "module linking" is a thing that exists, but it does not exist. In the command line you're looking at, `link` refers to spaCy's [`link` command](https://spacy.io/api/cli#link), which has nothing to do with Python modules.

Answer (score 3):

One potentially could say that "module linking" might refer to the actions taken by a linker during the process of compiling an extension module. This is not a commonly referred to step in usual Python development, even when working with extension modules (because the actions of the linker are generally implicit in some other compiler tool chain, and rarely treated as an isolated step, though in theory could be).

There is minimal discussion of e.g. linker options you might encounter at [this Cython documentation page](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html#compiling-from-the-command-line) for one example of this topic in an extension module setting.

Note that in the specific line of code you show,

```
python -m spacy link jieba zh
```

the `python -m spacy` part indicates that the spaCy module will be invoked directly with the interpreter, as a script, rather than its usual usage (imported from some other module or script).

The things following this, `link jieba zh`, are treated as space delimited arguments passed as `sys.argv` to the program defined by spaCy's script execution, so the meaning of `link` in this context is determined by whatever spaCy defines for processing that argument.